# How to modify main address of MS Office 365 group

Tags: powershell, office365

Hello I need to modify the main mail address of an Office 365 group.

How can I change 1st part and domain:

Example: 
I need to change admin@contoso.com to group@contoso.fr
How can I do this ?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already. Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing, and it's now possible (from january 2019!).
I found these commands who perfectly works:

1. Connect to PowerShell (with admin rights)
2. Allow Remote Signed scripts:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

3. Log with O365 admin user:

`$UserCredential = Get-Credential`

4. Create new session:

`$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection`

5. Import session:

`Import-PSSession $Session`

6. Set the new address:

`Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity admin@contoso.com -PrimarySmtpAddress group@contoso.fr`

That perfectly works for me, even if you're trying to send from external email.

Don't forget to return to the default execution policy:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Default
```

Enjoy it :)